# Continuity by composition with a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

I only want to know what do you guys think about  the following proof. That's an exercise I've tried to do and I don't have an available answer, so... If you find some error or imprecision, I'd be grateful!

**Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be topological spaces with $h:A \to B$ a homeomorphism. A function $f:B \to C$ is continuous if and only if $f \circ h : A \to C$ is continuous.**

**My try:** If $f:B \to C$ is continuous then, obviously, so is $f \circ h : A \to C$ ($h$ is continuous).
Suppose now that $f \circ h: A \to C$ is continuous and that $f: B \to C$ is not. Then exists an open subset $U$ of $C$ such that $f^{-1}(U) \subset B$ is not an open subset of $B$. But, since $f \circ h$ is continuous, we have $(f \circ h)^{-1}(U) \subset A$ open. That is, $h^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is open. Let $D=h^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$. Well, $D$ is open in $A$ and $h^{-1}$ is continuous, so $(h^{-1})^{-1}(D)$ is an open set of $B$, but
$$h(D)=h(h^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)))=f^{-1}(U),$$
and that is a contradiction.

This result says, in a certain sense, that is possible to consider $A$ instead of $B$ while studying the continuity of the function $f$.

Comment: You already used that composition of continuous functions is continuous. Why don't just use that to show the continuity of $f$?

Comment: Your proof is correct. You have basically shown that $h$ is a quotient map. A quotient map is a map $q:A\to B$ such that a function $f:B\to C$ is continuous if and only if $fq$ is continuous.

Comment: @user251257 composition of continuous functions is not an iff-statement.

Comment: @anakhronizein: wait? If $f\circ h$ is continuous and $h^{-1}$ is continuous, then $f=f\circ h \circ h^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Oh you had meant in addition to the fact $h$ is homeomorphic. I retract my comment in that light.

Comment: @anakhronizein: since it was part of the question, I thought it was clear ...

Comment: I had taken what you had said at face value. My mistake.

Comment: @user251257 : You've helped me so much! It's quite simpler than I've thought. Thank you

Comment: @user251257 You should write up your comment as the answer.